# UR5 communication via ethernet in C++

Tags: c++, tcp, ethernet

I am working on a project with computer vision and a UR5 robot.
Using a camera I acquire a X,Y,Z-coordinate. Now I need to transfer this coordinate to my UR5 robot.
I would like to do this with a ethernet cable in C++
Can anyone help me with this, I have found some articles on the UR support forum but these are written using C# and I can't get their library's (`using System; using System.Net; using System.Net.Sockets; using System.Text;`) to work in C++

Can anyone help me or does anyone know of a guide in C++ for doing this.

(The X,Y,Z-coordinate looks something like this X= 0,5341  Y = -0,01  Z = 0,480)

Answer (score 0):

ROS is used to control the UR5, so I'm considering that you're using ROS too. 
So you need to write a ROS-node in C++ that publishes your coordinate. And the UR5 will read from that ROS-node.

There's tutorial here. [Ros publisher](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29). It is just a few line of code.